# Having issues with Azure and SVG

Tags: azure, svg

We are having intermittent issues with SVG rendering after moving our website to Azure Web Sites.

**All** our svgs appears to load correctly the first time and then on refresh it returns a blank document which then makes chrome give you a `error on line 1 at column 1: Encoding error` error. If you view source all it shows random characters being returned by the server for example `!$`. Firefox returns `XML Parsing Error: not well-formed`

Hard refreshing doesn't work, but leaving it a while will make it work for one time again before it does the same thing again.

I've added in the web.config

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
</staticContent>
```

As suggested by other posts, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by setting doStaticCompression="false"

```
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="true" />
```

The above fixed my issue no other settings, but for the sake of completeness, here is the rest of my settings.

I also have

```
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
     </staticContent>
```

And

```
 <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
  <staticTypes>
    <remove mimeType="*/*" />
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </staticTypes>
  <dynamicTypes>
    <remove mimeType="*/*" />
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </dynamicTypes>
</httpCompression>
```